# Perl generate dynamic XML file

Tags: xml, perl

I have following XML that I want to create and populate with data through Perl script. In this XML I have some collection type of attributes i.e primarySiteCollection.

How do I dynamically populate and generate the 'primarySiteCollection' node.
In this XML the primarySiteCollection contain 3 tissue sites, but there can be 1 or many.

```
<TumorDetails>
    <personUpi>String</personUpi>
    <ageAtDiagnosis>3.14159E0</ageAtDiagnosis>
    <biopsyPathologyReportSummary>String</biopsyPathologyReportSummary>
    <primarySiteCollection>
        <tissueSite>
            <description>String1</description>
            <name>String1</name>
        </tissueSite>
        <tissueSite>
            <description>String2</description>
            <name>String2</name>
        </tissueSite>
        <tissueSite>
            <description>String3</description>
            <name>String3</name>
        </tissueSite>       
    </primarySiteCollection>
</TumorDetails>
```

This is my Perl script.
I wanted to generate the node dynamically containing collection type of attributes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Compile::Schema;

my $node = {
    personUpi                    => 'String',
    ageAtDiagnosis               => '3.14159E0',
    biopsyPathologyReportSummary => 'String',
    primarySiteCollection        => {
        tissueSite => {
            description => 'String',
            name        => 'String',
        },
    },
};

my $schema = XML::Compile::Schema->new('sample.xsd');
my $writer = $schema->compile(WRITER => 'TumorDetails');
my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new(q(1.0), q(UTF-8));

print $writer->($doc, $node)->toString;
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do.  Do you want to add data to this using a perl script?  If so, can you show us the perl script? Otherwise this comes across as a 'do my work for me' question, which generally aren't well received.

Comment: Absolutely not intended as you are saying above!

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: xsd always looked like overkill to me.  I'd just use a template.

Comment: This XML is so simple, you could do it with XML::Simple. It's not the best around, the stuff you have there is a lot more powerful, but still. It's simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is simple enough to do it safely with [XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSimple). If it was a lot more complicated, and you would have to take care of complex data types that are derived from objects, a schema would be very helpful. But for this, XML::Simple will do.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Simple;

my $tissueSite = [
  {
    description => 'String',
    name        => 'String',
  },
  {
    description => 'String2',
    name        => 'String2',
  },
];

my $data = {
  tumorDetails => {
    personUpi => 'String',
    ageAtDiagnosis => '3.14159E0',
    biopsyPathologyReportSummary => 'String',
    primarySiteCollection => {
        tissueSite => $tissueSite,
    },
  },
};

print XMLout($data, KeepRoot => 1, noAttr => 1 );
```

You can add more hashes to `$tissueSite`.

---

Remember, if it gets a lot more complicated, another approach is more suited.

Comment: On a different note, the keys in this data structure are kind of morbid. Brr.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I followed above approach , works fine.

But what if i don't know size of $tissueSite ( the number of hashes it will have ?) . It can extend/shrink to any size .

Suppose if i collect them in arrays : @decription and @names as per user inputs.

Is it possible to have $tissueSite creation with runtime values from above two arrays ?